# rails session being reset intermittently

Tags: session, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4

I know that this topic has been discussed a lot, but I believe that I've found a new variation of it: I have a Rails 4 application, which was upgraded from Rails 3, and which has the `rails_ujs` and `csrf_meta_tags` setup correctly.

Once the `root_url` is loaded in the browser, there is a javascript that fires a GET and a PUT, each one to its respective controller API in the application. By the moment those 2 API calls are fired, the session SHOULD have the `_csrf_token` there. And this is true, most of the times. Keep reading.

The problem is that, SOMETIMES, not always, we see some InvalidAuthenticityToken exceptions happening for the PUT request. (yes, I'm using `protect_from_forgery :with => :exception` on our API base controllers).

Analyzing the dump from `exception_notification`, I can see that the `CSRF_TOKEN` is setup correctly in the request header, but the most intriguing thing is that the session has only the `session_id` on it. Everything else is gone, including the `_csrf_token`.

Remember: this is happening intermittently! So I believe that it must be some kind of race condition.

This app is hosted on Heroku and running on Unicorn. I'm unable to reproduce the problem in my local environment. I've also read a lot of Rails code on github trying to understand the flows in which it resets the session, but I could not find the answer, since all CSRF protection is setup correctly and the problem happens intermittently.

It's also worth mentioning that we did not setup `config.secret_key_base` yet. But as this problem is happening intermittently, I don't think that this may be the root cause of it.

Also, I believe its worth mentioning that we have two controller hierarchies:

(1) all 'normal' application requests go through controllers which inherits from `ApplicationController`

(2) all API requests go through controllers which inherits from Api::BaseController, which inherits from `ActionController::Base` directly

I believe this controllers scheme is the most common for everybody...

The API endpoint for the GET request is rendering a json response. The API endpoint for the PUT request is returning `head :ok`.

Well, I would love if some Ruby on Rails expert could help on this.

Comment: Did you ever get anywhere with this?

Comment: Not yet... I'm still facing this problem. Have you ever seen something similar?

Comment: I've been stuck on this for days - managed to narrow it down to the fact that the session isn't being set at all... I've tried so many things to fix the original problem, it's going to take a while to back-step through it all.

Comment: I did research A LOT, but I could not find any solution... I don't think I'm the only one facing this problem, though. How come nobody else ever saw this happening? I believe its related to requests being served by different dynos on Heroku, but I don't have how to reproduce this locally.

Answer (score 2):

Are you using the standard cookie-based session store? The cookie-based session store, last i looked, most definitely was subject to race-conditions, especially around AJAX requests -- and the race conditions were kind of an inherent part of the design of a cookie-based session store, with no real way to fix it.

[This post from 2011](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2011/11/17/i-saw-an-extremely-subtle-bug-today-and-i-just-have-to-tell-someone/) describes a cookie store race condition that also involves the authenticity token, and may be similar to yours. Their solution was turning off the CSRF protection, for certain actions anyway, which doesn't sound like a great solution to me.

[This post from 2014](http://blog.bottega8.com/when-the-rails-magic-stops-cookies-storage-sessions/) outlines race conditions with cookie session store, and suggests ActiveRecord or other server-side store as a solution. (As i write this, that URL is 404'ing, but available in google cache).

> As you can see from the example, the session cookie is updated on every request, regardless of if the session was modified or not. Depending on when the response gets back to the client last, thats the cookie that will be used in the next call. For example, if in our previous example, if get_current_result’s response was slower than get_quiz, then our cookie would have the correct data and the next call to update_response would of work fine! So sometimes it will work and sometimes not all depending on the internet gods. This type of race condition is no fun to deal with.
>
> The implications of this is that using cookie storage for sessions when you are doing multiple ajax call is just not safe. All information saved in the session might be wrong or nonexistent next time you check. So whats the solution?
>
> ...
>
> A better solution would be to use a server side session store like active record or memcache. Doing so prevents the session data from being reliant on client side cookies. Session data no longer has to be passed between the client and the server which means no more potential race conditions when two ajax are simultaneously made!

I can't say for sure if you are running into that problem, but it would be worth a try to switch to the ActiveRecord cookie store, and see if your problem goes away.

Even the activerecord-based session store has at [times in the past been subject to race conditions](http://paulbutcher.com/2007/05/01/race-conditions-in-rails-sessions-and-how-to-fix-them/), I am not sure if the current implementation is, but they are at least conceivably solvable, whereas the race conditions in cookie-based store are fundamental.

The ActiveRecord store is probably subject to analagous race conditions to the cookie store actually -- IF you have more than one app process running (or a multi-threaded app server), so concurrent request handling is still possible, a very similar race condition is probably still possible. Although it should probably be even rarer than the race condition with the cookie store, *and* it is theoretically solvable, although perhaps with some domain-specific logic, unlike the race condition with the cookie store that is pretty much unsolvable if you are doing any async ajax.

Answer (score 1):

For better format, write this as an answer, maybe it should be a comment though.

I met a similar problem, the root reason is my app called `current_user` **before** `protect_from_forgery` executed, this is `current_user` implementation in Devise:

```
      def current_#{mapping}
        @current_#{mapping} ||= warden.authenticate(scope: :#{mapping})
      end
```

And Devise have a feature `config.clean_up_csrf_token_on_authentication = true`.

So the problem is, csrf token has been reset after `current_user` get invoked. because it calls `warden.authenticate`. Then when running `protect_from_forgery`. a csrf error has been raised. your session will be reset or an exception raised.

Hope this can help.